# Bad operand type for binary operator &&

Tags: types, binary, operand

I'm getting an error for the string of code below:

```
    int status = readInt("Status: ");
    double income = readDouble("Please enter your taxable income: ");
    println("You owe: ");

    if ((status = 0) && (income <= 9075))
```

It is giving me a 'bad operand type for binary operator &&' error and it's highlighting `&& (income <= 9075))` as where the issue is.  I'm sure it's something easy to figure out what's wrong but I can't; any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Which language? As Steve has pointed out, you've got an assignment where you probably intended a comparison, but it is not clear to me why that gives the error.  Specifically, neither C nor C++ could give an error.  It is important when you ask a question here to identify the language you are asking about, usually as one of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

status = 0 should be status == 0

Comment: True, but why would it cause the 'bad operand type' error?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because status = 0 returns an int, so you are basically doing int && bool which is invalid

Comment: In which language is that invalid?  It isn't wrong in either C or C++…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler c or c++ treats none zero int as true so it is fine. but high level languages such as c# or maybe java will give you this kind of error

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two ==, else the output will not be a condition.

```
 if ((status == 0) && (income <= 9075))
```